# How to set tabel in scrollpane and how to show tabel header

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
public class StatusPage extends JPanel
{
    DefaultTableModel dm;
    JTable table;
    JScrollPane jsb;

    public StatusPage()
    {
        String col_name[] = {"S.No.","Book Name","Author Name","Available Book","Issue Book","Total Book"};
        String data[][] = {{"1","Vikash","All","A","All","A"},{"1","Vikash","All","A","All","A"},{"1","Vikash","All","A","All","A"},{"1","Vikash","All","A","All","A"},{"1","Vikash","All","A","All","A"},{"1","Vikash","All","A","All","A"},{"1","Vikash","All","A","All","A"}};

        dm = new DefaultTableModel(data,col_name);
        table = new JTable(dm);
        jsb = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(table);
    }
}
```

please check error. Table header don't show. How to set size of table.I used Google but code can't work

Comment: [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the table header you should add `JScrollPane` instead of `table` in your panel or Frame

So you should do like this :

```
add(new JScrollPane(table));
```